# Songs with powerful real-life significance

Tags: history

I was listening to Vera Lynn's [We'll Meet Again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We%27ll_Meet_Again), which is an impactful song as it was popular among people going to World War II and their families left behind.

I was wondering what other songs have such powerful real-life associations?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "powerful real-life associations"? Something along the lines of ["Gloomy Sunday"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloomy_Sunday), also known as the "Hungarian Suicide Song"? Or something popular with soldiers during WW2 like ["Lili Marleen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lili_Marleen)

Comment: This seems to be a broad question. Especially, since nowadays each catastrophe gets a soundtrack assigned (think for example of Enya's 'Only time' and  9/11)

Answer (score 2):

Seems just about any song can have "real-life associations", e.g. it's easy to associate any love song with your own real-life love experiences. But if you mean broader real-life experiences, like a current event, then the list is long. Some examples that come to mind:

- Brother, Can You Spare a Dime?
- Ohio (Crosby, Stills, Nash & Young song)
- Abraham, Martin and John (Dick Holler/recorded by Dion)
- Tears in Heaven (Eric Clapton ... if you know the back-story)
- Hurricane (Bob Dylan)
- any anti-war song, really

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out some concept albums that are based on current events, personalities etc. One such album that I love and can relate to immensely is Hand. Cannot. Erase. by Steven Wilson. This album is inspired by the story of a Joyce Carol Vincent who lived in a large city in London. Joyce passed away and was not found until three years after her death. The album describes how life is in a big city in the 21st century and revolves around themes like relationships, isolation, nostalgia, and the effects of the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

A song that struck me will be Carrie Underwood's 'See You Again'

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTnWFT3DvVA

> I will see you again, oh
>
> This is not where it ends
>
> I will carry you with me, oh
>
> 'Till I see you again